# Using ternary operators instead of if statement when returning variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How could this conditional statement be simplified? Return statement is being used multiple times. Could for example ternary operators be used in this case?

Is returning null a proper way to hide Components?

```
import Item from './Item';

const Component = ({data, onChange}) => {

    if (data) {
        const items = data.map(( item ) => {
            return <Item onChange={ onChange } />
        });

        return(
            <ul>{items}</ul>
        );

    } else {
        return(null);
    }
}

export default Component;
```

Comment: Return early. Take the return out of the else, stick it at the top inside an `if(!data)` and then remove the other if statement.

Comment: Simplified? Hardly. Shortened? Sure, as usual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is returning null a proper way to hide Components?

Yes, returning null is a valid return value for a React Component. See [this section](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#booleans-null-and-undefined-are-ignored) of the official documentation:

> **Booleans, Null, and Undefined Are Ignored**
>
> `false`, `null`, `undefined`, and `true` are valid children. They simply don't render.

---

You could shorten your code a bit though:

```
const Component = ({data, onChange}) => (
  data && data.length ? <ul>
    {data.map(( item ) => <Item onChange={ onChange } />)}
  </ul> : null
)
```

Note however that you are not using `item` inside `<Item>`. Is that intentional? If so, you can write instead: `{data.map(() => <Item onChange={ onChange } />)}`

Also note that you need to provide a  `key` property to each `<Item>`. I have not added that to my snippet, but you can read more about the `key` prop, [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329382/understanding-unique-keys-for-array-children-in-react-js/43892905#43892905).

Comment: You can also remove the parenthesis around item, since it's a single parameter function. Also, you can remove the return keyword if you're not using a block in an arrow function.

Comment: @NimrodArgov, yes I missed the `return`. Fixed that, thanks. I like keeping the parenthesis, but that's just a personal preference.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't get to run it so there may be a bug in there somewhere, but would something like this be suitable?

```
const Component = ({data, onChange}) => {

  function returnItems(data){
    data.map(( item ) => <Item onChange={ onChange } />
    return(<ul>{items}</ul>);
  }

  const items = data ? returnItems(data) : null;
}
```